# Autofilter in Excel VBA - date equal works (=31.07.2021) different from date smaller (< 31.07.2021)

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, autofilter

I am trying to set a date autofilter in Excel VBA. When I try to enter:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$100").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & "31.10.2020"
```

it doesn't work, but it works when I enter (in US format):

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$100").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & "10/31/2020"
```

This works fine for me (Equal `31.10.20`) too:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$100").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=31.10.20"
```

How can I use both criteria with one date format (US, German)? And idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the ISO sequence:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$100").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & "2020/10/31"
```

Or try with a true date expression:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$100").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<#2020/10/31#"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$200").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=" & CDbl(DateSerial(2020, 7, 31))
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$200").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=" & "2020/10/31"
Only with "<" , but this works  "Criteria1:="=" & "31.10.2020". Looks like "=" and "<" are different in internal handling?

Comment: Perhaps you need a true date expression.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric dates in Excel are saved as number with `Double` precision in a cell and then formatted with number format "to look" german, american or whatever.

So the safest way is to take this `Double` number as criteria.

```
Criteria1:="<" & CDbl(DateSerial(2020, 10, 31))
```

`DateSerial` creates a real numeric date and `CDbl` turns it into a `Double`. In the end this will work for any number format as long as the dates in the cell are real numeric dates (which is highly recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Because I've needed a quick solution, I've split it into two ways:

If smaller_greater = True = True Then
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(RowsCount, ColumnCount)).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & US-FormatDateValue
Else
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(RowsCount, ColumnCount)).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=StandardDateValue
End If

This works fine for me. (Smaller_greater is based on the value I receive, e.g. "<31.10.2020" or "31.10.2020"